# Stacktrace is obfuscated in the Google Play console

Tags: android, deobfuscation, android-r8

I have a few apps on the store, and I'm seeing occasional crash reports.  However, the stacktrace remains obfuscated, even though the mapping file is showing as having been uploaded.

I'm using Android Studio, including the default settings for the new R8 code-shrinker.  A sample of the stacktrace is shown below.

```
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.Y (Fragment.java:31)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources (Fragment.java)
  at com.mysoftwarecompany.myappname.PersonalInfoFragment.ca (PersonalInfoFragment.java:49)
  at com.mysoftwarecompany.myappname.PersonalInfoFragment.access$400 (PersonalInfoFragment.java)
  at com.mysoftwarecompany.myappname.PersonalInfoFragment$8.onSharedPreferenceChanged (PersonalInfoFragment.java:2)
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.notifyListeners (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:607)
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:489)
  at com.mysoftwarecompany.myappname.PersonalInfoFragment$4.onItemSelected (PersonalInfoFragment.java:39)
  at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected (AdapterView.java:947)
  at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected (AdapterView.java:936)
  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300 (AdapterView.java:56)
  at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run (AdapterView.java:901)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:907)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7593)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you enabled obfuscation using proguard.

Comment: I'm aware that obfuscation is enabled (via R8, not proguard, I think), but why is the uploaded deobfuscation file not working?  How do I get the stacktrace to be usable?

Comment: You need mapping.txt file to do it. You can follow https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6295281

Comment: The mapping file is already uploaded, as stated in the question.

Comment: This could be a bug in the generation of the mapping file. Please open a bug on R8 [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938), so we can look into it. If possible attach the mapping file to the bug, or if you don't want the mapping file on a public bug you can share it privately with sgjesse@google.com and mjkrogh@google.com.

You can also take a look at the mapping file to see if the mappings for `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `com.mysoftwarecompany.myappname.PersonalInfoFragment` to look for mappings to `Y` and `ca`.

Comment: Thank you, @sgjesse , bug report filed and email sent as per your comment.

Comment: @sgjesse Whether the above issue resolved? Even we are facing the same maapping.txt automatically uploaded in the new console(AppbundleExplorer->Downloads) but in the stack trace, line numbers are not printing.